# Mysql backup strategy

Tags: backup, mysql

I was wondering whats the best way to backup MySQL (v5.1.x) data -

- creating mysql data dir archive
- use mysqldump

What are the pro/cons for the above? I am guessing mysqldump has some performance impact on a live database. How much impact are we talking about?

We plan to take a backup every few hours, lets say 4 hrs. Whats the best practice around MySQL backups or database backups in general.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943028/mysqldump-or-mysqlhotcopy-to-backup-large-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is using mysqldump.

Normally I create a cron task to run in a time of little traffic, it generate a dump naming with a timestamp_databasename_enviroment.sql, so it verify if there are old backups and compact it.

I think that is a good form to do database backups.

Comment: If you do it in a time of low traffic, the impact is small, or even imperceptible. I have a application with 4.000 use for hour average and I user this scheme to backup my database. normally I run it on dawn.

Comment: You needs watch  disc space, because as time the backups size will be increased

Answer (score 0):

If your data size is huge then its better to use

- *MySQL enterprise backup* tools.it takes online backup and it will not impact live services.
- xtraback is also like  MySQL enterprise backup from percona .